# Is there a way to overcome CORS issue using service workers in angular on reopen browser

Tags: angular, authentication, cors, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I am implementing **Service-workers** in my Angular(v7.2.1) application.

- my server hides behind NetIQ which regulated authentication process.
- NetIQ then redirects to my application after successful login in. Application works fine for the first time.
- When i close the browser and try to open application again,I see a blank screen.
- Unable to access service API's **nor** Getting redirected to NetIQ, It throws a CORS issue as seen below.
- works fine when i hard reload it again

Below is the code which i used for Service Workers registration. Is there a way i can access API's without hard reloading the browser.

[image: Error while accessing same service on browser reopen]

```
---- main.js----


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

```
----ngsw-config.js----


{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```